# Add timezone support to node.js + later

Tags: node.js, cron, timezone

I'm writing an app that allows users to have the app send them reminders based on a cron spec, and for this I'm using nodejs and [later](https://github.com/bunkat/later). The use of nodejs is a requirement.

The later library allows me to calculate the next occurrence based on the cron spec entered by the user.

The problem is that all calculations of the next occurrence can either only be based on the UTC time, or local server time. However, I need it to change dynamically based on the user's own timezone.

I thought about calculating the next occurrence first then calculating an offset for the next run, but that will not work if the user creates a cron spec that says "once every hour"!

Anyone have any creative ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron-node has timezone support. It's not meant just for finding the next occurrence, it actually implements callbacks in code to execute for each job...however it seems like you can call sendAt() directly from a CronTime object to get the next occurrence.